# Compass doens't regenerate sprite after image's name

Tags: ruby, compass-sass

I just install and try compass.

I did `compass create compass_test`

I create a images/icons folder and put several .png file in it.
In sass I create a file icons.scss with

```
@import "icons/*.png";
@include all-icons-sprites;
```

When I do a`compass compile` for the first time or when I add a new file it does generate the sprite and css file.
But when I modify the name of a .png file or removed it, it doens't notice the difference.

Is there any way to ask compass to recompile the file when filename are changing or deleted ?

Thanks for you help !

Answer (score 3):

Delete the generated stylesheet file that is importing the sprite's directory.